# Using MATLAB area() to shade graph error in matlab2tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I generate a graph in MATLAB and want to shade regions. So I use the area() command and set it to display in the right order.

MATLAB code for the graph:

```
hold on 
x = 0:1:5;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y);
h(1) = area([0.2 0.8], [2 2],'EdgeColor',[1.0 0.8 0.4]);
h(2) = area([0.8 1.5], [2 2],'EdgeColor',[1.0 0.6 0.2]);
set(h(1),'FaceColor',[1.0 0.8 0.4]);
set(h(2),'FaceColor',[1.0 0.6 0.2]);
set(gca,'children',flipud(get(gca,'children')));
```

Makes this gorgeous plot:

[image]

Full latex MWE (the generated .tikz code from matlab2tikz will be between the `tikzpicture` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=4.5in,
height=3.5in,
area style,
stack plots=y,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=5,
ymin=-1,
ymax=2,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\addplot[fill=white!20!orange,draw=white!20!orange] plot table[row sep=crcr]{0.8    2\\
1.5 2\\
}
\closedcycle;
\addplot[fill=mycolor1,draw=mycolor1] plot table[row sep=crcr]{0.2  2\\
0.8 2\\
}
\closedcycle;
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{0 0\\
1   0.841470984807897\\
2   0.909297426825682\\
3   0.141120008059867\\
4   -0.756802495307928\\
5   -0.958924274663138\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When I try and compile it in latex I get the error:

`! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, pgfplots expects stacked plots to have exactly
the same number of coordinates.`

I think this is a glitch in matlab2tikz so I will report it, but either way I do  not know how to fix it for my example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you have expected? after removing `stack plots=y`, it compiles. Since the code does not have `mycolor1` defined. This solution use different color instead.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=4.5in,
height=3.5in,
area style,
%stack plots=y,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=5,
ymin=-1,
ymax=2,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\addplot[fill=white!20!orange,draw=white!20!orange] plot table[row sep=crcr]{0.8 2\\
1.5 2\\
}
\closedcycle;
\addplot[fill=yellow!20!red,draw=yellow!20!red] plot table[row sep=crcr]{0.2  2\\
0.8 2\\
}
\closedcycle;
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{0 0\\
1   0.841470984807897\\
2   0.909297426825682\\
3   0.141120008059867\\
4   -0.756802495307928\\
5   -0.958924274663138\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's perfect, removing `stack plots=y` fixes this. Thank you very much.